# how to get input value from ultrasonic sensor on copper web application (coap protocol)

Tags: c, esp8266, coap, arduino-ultra-sonic

i can't use 'GET' in copper.I know that ultrasonic sensors can't be set like lights (binary data). but I just want to get a description of the if parameter I've made

```
   if (jarak < 50) {
    Serial.println ("jarak Aman ");
    
    }
   
   else {
    Serial.println ("harus diisi");
```

this is the full code

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <coap_server.h>
#include <Ultrasonic.h>


#define triggerPin  D8
#define echoPin     D7

char * duration, jarak;

coapServer coap;

//WiFi connection info
const char* ssid = "ZTE-d17d4e";
const char* password = "amatapit";

bool LEDSTATE;

//Setup


void setup() {
  yield();


  pinMode(triggerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  //serial begin
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println(" ");

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    //delay(500);
    yield();
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  
  // LED State
  pinMode(16, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(16, HIGH);
  LEDSTATE = true;

  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  //LEDSTATE = true;




  // add server url endpoints.
  // can add multiple endpoint urls.

  coap.server(callback_light, "light");
  coap.server(callback_sensor, "sensor");

  // start coap server/client
  coap.start();
  // coap.start(5683);
}

void loop() {
  coap.loop();
  delay(1000);

long duration, jarak;
   
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
   //inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
//    cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
   jarak = duration/29/2;
   Serial.print("Jarak :");
   Serial.println(jarak);
   Serial.print(" cm");
   Serial.println("");
   if (jarak < 50) {
    Serial.println ("jarak Aman ");
    
    }
   
   else {
    Serial.println ("harus diisi");
   }
   
  delay(500);


}



// CoAP server endpoint URL
void callback_light(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port,int obs) {
  Serial.println("light");

  // send response
  char p[packet->payloadlen + 1];
  memcpy(p, packet->payload, packet->payloadlen);
  p[packet->payloadlen] = NULL;
  Serial.println(p);

  String message(p);

  if (message.equals("0"))
  {
    digitalWrite(16,LOW);
    Serial.println("Lampu Mati");
  }
  else if (message.equals("1"))
  {
    digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
    Serial.println("Lampu Menyala");
  } 
  char *light = (digitalRead(16) > 0)? ((char *) "Lampu Menyala:") :((char *) "Lampu Mati");
  
   //coap.sendResponse(packet, ip, port, light);
   if(obs==1)
    coap.sendResponse(light);
   else
    coap.sendResponse(ip,port,light);
 
}


void callback_sensor(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port,int obs) {
  Serial.println("sensor");

// send response
  char p[packet->payloadlen + 1];
  memcpy(p, packet->payload, packet->payloadlen);
  p[packet->payloadlen] = NULL;
  Serial.println(p);

  String message(p);
 if (message.equals("1"))
  {
   // digitalWrite(16,LOW);
    Serial.println(jarak);
  }
  else if (message.equals("2"))
  {
   // digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
    Serial.println(jarak);
  } 


  
  char *sensor = ((jarak) > 0)? ((char *) "Nyala nih") :((char *) "Mati");
 
  
  
   //coap.sendResponse(packet, ip, port, sensor);
   if(obs==1)
    coap.sendResponse(sensor);
   else
    coap.sendResponse(ip,port,sensor);
}#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <coap_server.h>
#include <Ultrasonic.h>


#define triggerPin  D8
#define echoPin     D7

char * duration, jarak;

coapServer coap;

//WiFi connection info
const char* ssid = "ZTE-d17d4e";
const char* password = "amatapit";

bool LEDSTATE;

//Setup


void setup() {
  yield();


  pinMode(triggerPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
  //serial begin
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println(" ");

  // Connect to WiFi network
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print("Connecting to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    //delay(500);
    yield();
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println("WiFi connected");
  // Print the IP address
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());

  
  // LED State
  pinMode(16, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(16, HIGH);
  LEDSTATE = true;

  pinMode(5, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(5, HIGH);
  //LEDSTATE = true;




  // add server url endpoints.
  // can add multiple endpoint urls.

  coap.server(callback_light, "light");
  coap.server(callback_sensor, "sensor");

  // start coap server/client
  coap.start();
  // coap.start(5683);
}

void loop() {
  coap.loop();
  delay(1000);

long duration, jarak;
   
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  delayMicroseconds(2); 
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, HIGH);
  delayMicroseconds(10); 
  digitalWrite(triggerPin, LOW);
  duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
   //inches = microsecondsToInches(duration);
//    cm = microsecondsToCentimeters(duration);
   jarak = duration/29/2;
   Serial.print("Jarak :");
   Serial.println(jarak);
   Serial.print(" cm");
   Serial.println("");
   if (jarak < 50) {
    Serial.println ("jarak Aman ");
    
    }
   
   else {
    Serial.println ("harus diisi");
   }
   
  delay(500);


}



// CoAP server endpoint URL
void callback_light(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port,int obs) {
  Serial.println("light");

  // send response
  char p[packet->payloadlen + 1];
  memcpy(p, packet->payload, packet->payloadlen);
  p[packet->payloadlen] = NULL;
  Serial.println(p);

  String message(p);

  if (message.equals("0"))
  {
    digitalWrite(16,LOW);
    Serial.println("Lampu Mati");
  }
  else if (message.equals("1"))
  {
    digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
    Serial.println("Lampu Menyala");
  } 
  char *light = (digitalRead(16) > 0)? ((char *) "Lampu Menyala:") :((char *) "Lampu Mati");
  
   //coap.sendResponse(packet, ip, port, light);
   if(obs==1)
    coap.sendResponse(light);
   else
    coap.sendResponse(ip,port,light);
 
}


void callback_sensor(coapPacket *packet, IPAddress ip, int port,int obs) {
  Serial.println("sensor");

// send response
  char p[packet->payloadlen + 1];
  memcpy(p, packet->payload, packet->payloadlen);
  p[packet->payloadlen] = NULL;
  Serial.println(p);

  String message(p);
 if (message.equals("1"))
  {
   // digitalWrite(16,LOW);
    Serial.println(jarak);
  }
  else if (message.equals("2"))
  {
   // digitalWrite(16,HIGH);
    Serial.println(jarak);
  } 


  
  char *sensor = ((jarak) > 0)? ((char *) "Nyala nih") :((char *) "Mati");
 
  
  
   //coap.sendResponse(packet, ip, port, sensor);
   if(obs==1)
    coap.sendResponse(sensor);
   else
    coap.sendResponse(ip,port,sensor);
}
```

Comment: What is exact your question? you have problem in getting sensor reading or you have problem in sending data via COAP? Also, edit your code, you seems to post the code twice.

Answer (score 0):

To analyse the issue, you may also try other clients, e.g. [libcoap](https://github.com/obgm/libcoap) or [Californium](https://github.com/eclipse/californium). If that still results in trouble, a [IP capture](https://github.com/eclipse/californium/wiki/Logs-and-IP-Capturing-%E2%80%90-How-To-Provide-The-Right-Information) helps to understand the case.

Or, is your question more about your server-side code than about coap? Then some logs from your server may help to understand, how it works and to find the issue there.